# Is it possible to use latex in the minted environment outside of comments?

Tags: minted

I am wondering if it's possible to add a bit code in latex, perhaps by using some kind of escape character, to mark parts of the minted environment that should be executed as regular latex code?

Comment: do you mean similar to `escapeinside` from the `listings` package?

Comment: @cmhughes: Yes. Or some way of achieving the same goal in the minted environment, even if it doesn't involve escaped text.

Comment: `minted` has `texcl` and `mathescape` options which are used as their equivalents in `listings`. Are these enough for you?

Comment: Unfortunately these are only used in comments. I can't see an `escapeinside` equivalent in the manual.

Comment: @hpesoj626 I guess the problem is that `minted` leaves the parsing to another tool (Pygments), and this makes dropping out of the parser to do formatting 'hard'.

Comment: Pygments doesn't support this. It's been [requested](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issue/493/optionally-enable-escaping-to-latex) since 2010, and based on the patch with that request, it should be feasible. Just hasn't been done.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer here is 'no': unlike `listings`, `minted` relies on Pygments for processing and it would come down to support in this tool. There is an [open request](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issue/493/optionally-enable-escaping-to-latex) for this ability, but it's been that way since 2010 despite a patch being provided.